# FullCalendar HTML5 Drag & Drop Api

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar

I wanted to be able to drag and drop from multiple monitors, so I could have a list of tasks on one monitor and drag over to the second monitor's calendar. This wasn't feasible with the current implementation of JQuery UI because the scope is limited to the same window.

After playing around I found a hacky way to make this work for my needs. The answer still needs modifications but it could guide you if you are looking for something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this will still need some tweaking down the line but was able to get FullCalendar to work with HTML5 Drag & Drop API. Basically I'm using math to know where the item was dropped on the calendar and which time slot. I'm using the eventAfterAllRender feature built into full calendar to add my logic. This works for me and may be able to help you or get you in the right direction. On drop I'm setting a private onDrop function that takes the date/time to in which the item was dropped on. (Currently I do not have it as a momentjs object but plan to).

```
//Global Variables
var onDrop = null;
var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };

eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
                var currentDate = null;
                var currentTime = null;
                var dateRange = [];
                var timeRange = [];

                if (view.type == 'month') {
                    $('.fc-widget-content').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).attr('data-date') != null) {
                            var bounds = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect();

                            dateRange.push({
                                date: $(this).attr('data-date'),
                                bounds: bounds
                            })
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $('.fc-widget-header').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).attr('data-date') != null) {
                            var bounds = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect();

                            dateRange.push({
                                date: $(this).attr('data-date'),
                                bounds: bounds
                            })
                        }
                    });

                    $('.fc-slats tr').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).attr('data-time') != null) {
                            var bounds = $(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect();

                            timeRange.push({
                                time: $(this).attr('data-time'),
                                bounds: bounds
                            })
                        }
                    });
                }

                $(document).mousemove(function (event) {
                    currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
                    currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;

                    currentDate = null;
                    currentTime = null;

                    for (var dIdx = 0; dIdx < dateRange.length; ++dIdx) {
                        if (dateRange[dIdx].bounds.left <= currentMousePos.x && dateRange[dIdx].bounds.right > currentMousePos.x) {
                            if (view.type == 'month') {
                                if (dateRange[dIdx].bounds.top < currentMousePos.y && dateRange[dIdx].bounds.bottom >= currentMousePos.y) {
                                    currentDate = dateRange[dIdx];
                                    break;
                                }
                            } else {
                                currentDate = dateRange[dIdx];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    for (var tIdx = 0; tIdx < timeRange.length; ++tIdx) {
                        if (timeRange[tIdx].bounds.top < currentMousePos.y && timeRange[tIdx].bounds.bottom >= currentMousePos.y) {
                            currentTime = timeRange[tIdx];
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (currentDate != null && currentTime != null) {
                        var originalOnDrop = onDrop;
                        if (onDrop != null) {
                            onDrop = null;
                            if (originalOnDrop != null) {
                                originalOnDrop(currentDate.date + ' ' + currentTime.time);
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (currentDate != null) {
                        var originalOnDrop = onDrop;
                        if (onDrop != null) {
                            onDrop = null;
                            if (originalOnDrop != null) {
                                originalOnDrop(currentDate.date);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

//HTML5 Drag Event Captured
self.HandleDrop = function (command, data) {
    switch (command) {
        case 'Workorder':
            onDrop = function (date) {
                $('#myTime').html(date);
                console.log(command);
                console.log(data);
            }
            break;
    } 
}
```